# ¿Como ingresar 4 datos a un array en php por teclado, comparar y saber cual es el mayor?

Tags: php

¿Como ingresar 4 datos a un array en php por teclado, comparar el primer dato con el segundo y que diga cual de los datos es mayor, despues comparar tambien el tercer dato con el cuarto y tambien saber cual de los dos es mayor? ayuda soy nuevo en php

Comment: y muestra que error tienes y que haz hecho ya

Comment: $nota[]= 7;
$nota[]= 5;
$nota[]= 2;
$nota[]= 4;

Comment: eso son los datos que yo le puse al array, pero esos datos yo quiero ingresar por teclado

Comment: pero agrega en tu pregunta y cual es el error que estas teniendo?

Comment: no tengo ningun error solo no se como ingresar los datos al array por teclado sin necesidad de poner esto $nota[]= 7;
$nota[]= 5;
$nota[]= 2;
$nota[]= 4;

Comment: con lo que investige se puede hacer con formulario

Comment: Si. Mediante un formulario podrías hacerlo. Hace un sitio con un formulario con 4 textbox y en el php hace el calculo. Si son 4 entradas no hace falta que tengas 4 arrays, Solo un array con 4 posiciones

Comment: si con el formulario se puede hacer, la cuestion es que no se como jeje.

Comment: busca ejemplo en google de hacer un formulario en html y php. Va a tener una idea. Existe mucha documentación sobre ello.